# Making Triangular div clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've to make triangle area clickable . The problem i'm facing is these triangles have their transparent parts overlapping. Is there any way I can make the transparent part of the triangle unclickable? 
This is how I'm making a triangle

CSS:

```
 .tri{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 88px solid transparent;
    border-right: 88px solid transparent;
   border-top: 121px solid transparent; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
   z-index:10;
   position:absolute;
   text-align:center;
    color: white;
   font-size:15px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/haba7x2g/2

Comment: Please add your HTML and JS or a fiddle link.

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle so that its easy for us to resolve the issue

Comment: @Reddy there is already the JSfiddle on the end of the question.

Comment: @eg16 Fiddle was added after my comment :)

Comment: @Reddy You asked 17 mins ago, the edit was done 9 mins ago -> You are right. Sorry :)

Comment: @eg16 no issues :) I knew you dint realize the timing

Comment: I spent some time with different approaches But I couldn't solve it.. However if your intention is to just get that pie chart look then you can simply use SVG tag and draw them, This way there are no elements overlapped and it makes life easier

Comment: Thank You :) @Reddy

Answer (score 0):

Just include `jQuery cdn` in your project/jsfiddle.
check this: https://jsfiddle.net/haba7x2g/1/

Comment: Check the console , its not the proper output . Problem is : divs are overlapping, so when I'm clicking on triangle1 ,its showing triangle 5 is clicked .

Comment: Added jsfiddle link. output is in developer console

Comment: click on the corners of the triangle and you see different outputs

Comment: CSS needs to be properly implemented. You can try like this: https://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish